# Ajax post and Code Igniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I need to send 2 values to my codeigniter controller complete the request. But I failed in all attempts.

My Controller need to receive:

```
$token = $this->input->post('cc_token');
$hash = $this->input->post('sender_hash');
```

Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function ({
    var sender_hash = myfunction.getSenderHash();

    var card_token = myFunction.createCardToken({
        cardNumber: "4111111111111111",
        brand: 'visa',
        cvv: "123",
        expirationMonth: "12",
        expirationYear: "2030",
        success: function (response) {

        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
    $("#submit").click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $details->id?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'cc_token=' + card_token + '&sender_hash=' + sender_hash,
            beforeSend: function () {
                console.log("Your request is being processed. Wait...");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Thank you for donating. Your request has been successfully processed!");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("There was an error sending the data. Try again.")
            }

        });
    });
});
```

But the post was not send to controller. What i'm doing wrong? If i put these values in input, works fine, but I don't wanna to do that, because this is not the right way.

Comment: need to prevent default event on #submit if it is a form `submit` button. Url seems fishy also

Comment: I already tried to do this. Don't worked. I passed full URL too, and don't worked. =/. Only thing that happens is that no longer returns the error that didn't find the token.

Comment: need to inspect actual request in browser dev tools network for clues. Without basic troubleshooting information to isolate client vs server side issues not much we can do

Comment: I tried now and I can't get any information about requests...I don't what's happening. =(

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: are you sure that card_token and sender_hash have a value?

Comment: Console just show the success and beforesend messages.

Comment: Yes. Because I can put the values in console.

Comment: I think you lost in URL value, what is the value of the $details->id? try checking it by view page source.

Comment: My URL is: https://localhost/panel/donate/pay/11

Comment: If JS code is in separated js file PHP code in it (i.e. base_url function) won't work. In that case you should put JS code in view file (i.e. php file you load as view from controller).

Comment: The problem was already solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below with `base_url()`

Make sure you have setup the `base_url` in `config.php`

**Goto:** `application->config->config.php`

Also auto load the `url` helper

**Goto:** `application->config->autoload.php`

And try the below code,

```
$(document).ready(function ({
    var sender_hash = myfunction.getSenderHash();

        var hash = '';

    var card_token = myFunction.createCardToken({
        cardNumber: "4111111111111111",
        brand: 'visa',
        cvv: "123",
        expirationMonth: "12",
        expirationYear: "2030",
        success: function (response) {
                    hash = response;
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/donate/pay/<?php echo $details->id?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'cc_token':hash,'sender_hash':sender_hash},
            beforeSend: function () {
                console.log("Your request is being processed. Wait...");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Thank you for donating. Your request has been successfully processed!");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("There was an error sending the data. Try again.")
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @peter97 What is your `base_url` ??

Comment: https://localhost/painel/. If I put token and hash value in input field "$('#token').val(card_token); and send when submit form,  works fine. But I dont want to do that, because this is not the "right" way.

Comment: Ok...What is the response your getting in `createCardToken` ??

Comment: 53314c73d7034baca9d843ba0dedbb3a

Comment: @peter97 where is the `index.php` ??

Comment: It's not necessary to put  index.php

Comment: What is int the console??...Try `console.log(data);` and tell me the output